# How to uninstall/remove "Snipping Tool" from start menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, start-menu

Is there a way to uninstall/remove Snipping Tool so only Snip and Sketch appears when I search for "snip" in the Start Menu?

Microsoft made "Snip and Sketch" to replace "Snipping Tool." So when you start "Snipping Tool" it asks if you want to start "Snip and Sketch." I actually prefer using "Snip and Sketch," however I often forget which one is which after searching for "snip" in the Start Menu. I have no need for the old Snipping Tool.

I cannot find an option to uninstall it. I tried:

- Settings App > Apps & Features
- Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Programs and Features
- Microsoft Store

There is also a registry setting/group policy but that only disables the ability to run Snipping Tool; it still exists in the Start Menu.

Comment: Note that you can use Win + Shift + S to launch the tool. You can also change the Print Screen key to open Snip & Sketch. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-take-and-annotate-screenshots-on-windows-10-ca08e124-cc30-2579-3e55-6db63e36fbb9

Comment: As Didier has said, you can just set print screen as the short cut for snip and sketch. A lot quicker and easier to use

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Remove the shortcut from `%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories` (You can find this folder from the Start Menu. See image at end.)
2. Wait for the Start Menu index to update itself.

---

**update:** There are also two convenient keyboard shortcuts to start Snip & Sketch:

1. <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> ([Must first enable from "Ease of Access Keyboard Settings"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-take-and-annotate-screenshots-on-windows-10-ca08e124-cc30-2579-3e55-6db63e36fbb9))
2. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (Enabled by default)

The <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> shortcut is very convenient. I still suggest removing "Snipping Tool" so "Snip & Sketch" becomes the best match in the Start Menu and automatically shows options like "New snip in 10 seconds."

---

How to find the directory containing the Start Menu shortcut file to delete:
[image]

Comment: In my testing, it seems that whatever you used last becomes the "Best match" next time you search -- so if I search "snip" and click Snip & Sketch under the "Apps" header, the next time I search "snip" it will list Snip & Sketch under "Best match" and Snipping Tool will be under "Apps".